# Install tensorflow on windows python 3.6

Tags: python, tensorflow, command-prompt

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

This message is shown when I try to `pip install`.  I have tried it with python 3.7 when it didn't work. I also tried it with 3.6 and I still tensorflow can't install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Christoph Gohlke's packages: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tensorflow

Download the package for Python 3.6, then use `pip install` on the package:

```
pip install tensorflow‑1.9.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Note that you will need the NumPy + MKL packages and the Protobuf packages that can be downloaded from Christoph Gohlke's website as well.

- NumPy + MKL: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy
- Protobuf: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#protobuf

Make sure you choose the Python 3.6 version.  You can determine this by looking at the numbers after the `cp` in the filename (i.e. `cp36`).... so what you'll actually need to do is download the three wheels, then install them in the following order:

```
pip install numpy‑1.16.3+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
pip install protobuf‑3.7.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
pip install tensorflow‑1.9.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

---

*Note:* I'm assuming you're using a 64-bit version of Windows which is the default type for many Windows installations.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it using the following command

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.13.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: 'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. This is the error message.

Comment: Try just `python`

Comment: Note the OP is on Windows. It looks like you're pointing to a Mac OS build.